# Вопрос по FileReader в Java

Tags: java, файлы

Стоит задача считать с файла только четные по индексу символы. Например в файле "123456789", считать "2468".
Написал код:

```
    int j = 1;

    FileReader fIn = new FileReader(fileName1);

    while (fIn.ready()) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            list.add((char) fIn.read());
        }
        System.out.println(list.toString()); //Check
        j++;
    }
```

В консоль вывелось.

> []
>
> []
>
> [, 1]
>
> [, 1]
>
> [, 1, 2]
>
> [, 1, 2]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>
> [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Вопрос:

1. Почему в список добавились все символы из файла, хотя стоит проверка.
2. Почему выводятся по два раза list.toString, а последний один раз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в любом случае считаете все символы, т.к. считывание происходит только в случае кратности счетчика.

Нужно считать и пропускать ненужные символы:

```
int j = 1;
FileReader fIn = new FileReader(fileName1);

while (fIn.ready()) {
    char c = (char) fIn.read();
    if (j % 2 == 0) {
        list.add(c);
    }
    System.out.println(list.toString()); //Check
    j++;
}
```

Comment: Да, я с этим уже разобрался и не стал редактировать вопрос, спасибо. Но вот насчет второго я так и не пойму, почему по два вывода на экран.

Comment: Там причина в одном и том же -- считывается из файла и добавляется в список при одном и том же условии, но вывод вы делаете всегда, поэтому два вывода подряд с одним и тем же значением. Для лучшего понимания выводите так же `j`: `System.out.println("=" + j + " " + list);`

Answer (score 1):

Можно читать файл с произвольного места. Например четные по индексу символы:

```
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");

    for (long i = 1; i < raf.length(); i += 2) {
        byte[] symbol = new byte[1];
        raf.seek(i);
        raf.read(symbol);
        System.out.println(new String(symbol)); // 2 4 6 8
    }
```